# How to access ArrayCollection Data

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, arraycollection

I know this one might be easy but I couldn't figure out.

I have a List control that retrieve multiply data from Mysql. When a use clicks the data on List, The datagrid will display the data and the product image will show.

I can see the multiply data shown in my dataGrid, but I don't know how to get the individual data shown. I am not sure if I explain the questoin well. Please see the code below and thanks for any reply.

```
<s:List id="compList"
width="250"
height="350"
creationComplete="compList_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
itemRenderer="itemRenderer.compListItemRenderer"
change="compList_changeHandler(event)"  //when a user select a row, the datagrid will display the data.
>
<s:AsyncListView list="{compinfoResult.lastResult}"/>

</s:List>




<mx:DataGrid id="dataGrid" dataProvider="{compDetailinfoResult.lastResult}">      //The dataGrid display the data fine
<mx:columns>
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="user" headerText="User"/>
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="brand" headerText="Brand"/>
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="compModel" headerText="Model"/>
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="picture" headerText="Product Picture"/>
</mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>


<mx:Image source="??????" />   // I want to display productPicture here too but not sure what to add here.....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Something like this:

```
<mx:Image source="{dataGrid.selectedItem.sourcelocation}" />
```

It would be easier to be more specific if you had a running sample and/or an explanation of the value objects that make up your list.  Your approach seems odd to me; as it appears you are using a DataGrid to display a single item.  Is that correct?  DataGrids are good for displaying multiple, similar, items in a table like format; I'm not sure if I'd use it for a single item.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I didn't explain the question well.  I want the user to click the List control data and display the product details on both datagrid and the image control. I do have multiply items displayed in my dataGrid (see code above). Your code is for the user that clicks on the datagrid data instead of List. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: Never mind. I think I got it now. My question wasn't that clear. 
+1 and accepted answer for u.

Comment: I hope I helped.  I don't understand what it means to multiple items.  BTW, my code has nothing to do w/ clicking the DataGrid.  Clicking is only one way to select items on a DataGrid [or List]  Thanks for the rep, though.